# How to make a little helper to guide visitors through my configurator (example included)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I build a configurator so that visitors can drag and drop things to a specific area on my page. What I now need is a little "helper" which guides the visitor through the process. I thought something like this would be perfect: https://www.cubit-shop.com/en-uk/shelf/configurator

I'm talking about the marker for the "drop area", the arrow and the text "simply drag the modules to the design area".

Obviously this helper should be there if the visitor opens the page and then should disappear when he clicked the first time anywhere.

How could this be done?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: One more question: When hovering over an element in the above mentioned example, then it shows a window with additional information. How is this done?
Thanks again

Comment: Can you narrow your question down a bit ? It is quite broad. Simply put it can be done By adding overlay, which you only show on the first time user lands on the page (by cookie or maybe by adding a "seen" in your db)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as specific as possible, as claimed in the rules. But thanks for your help. So just an CSS overlay?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously tried http://introjs.com/ but it depends on what you need it for, since its paid for commercial use.

Alternatively you can try 
http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/
 and 
http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/

Look around and you will find even more libraries that will help you achieve that, but I think these will do just fine.